# Any concurrency issues in declaring a LongPredicate (or similar) as private static instead of non-static class variable

Tags: java, lambda, static, java-stream, predicate

I have declared a `LongPredicate` as:

```java
private LongPredicate isAboveZero = id -> id > 0L;
```

Since this is a non-capturing `lambda` isn't it better to declare it as `static`?

Also, when declared `static`, will there be any concurrency issue if it is accessed by multiple threads or if used with parallel `streams`?

Comment: Well, your lambda will result in an anonymous class implementing `LongPredicate` and since that class won't have any state there should be no concurrency issues involved with the lambda itself. Btw, I assume `isAboveZero` will never change at runtime so you might as well declare it `final`.

Comment: “at class level” implies `static`, so it’s a strange question whether it is better to declare it `static`. Without `static`, it isn’t class level and wasting memory in every instance of your class. Regarding concurrency, as Thomas said there are no issue and if there were, you had them anyway, as without `static` you have a distinct reference variable in each instance but it still refers to the same `Predicate` object in practice.

Comment: @Thomas I think you can add that as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the [specification on Lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-LambdaExpression) you get the following:

> A lambda expression is like a method: ...

and

> Evaluation of a lambda expression produces an instance of a functional interface.

That means you basically get an anonymous class implementing `LongPredicate` and since that class just has one method and no state it is thread-safe - unless the method is doing non-thread-safe things which is not the case in the expression you've posted.

This means it would be fine to store the reference to the instance of that class in a static variable. However, you might also want to make `isAboveZero` final so it can't get replaced at runtime (see my comment as well).